# G+ number stuck on 0 - "+1" not recorded

Tags: google-plus, counter, google-plus-one

I have an issue with my website http://www.kuhm.fr/ and the "+1" on all pages (like http://www.kuhm.fr/erreurs-communes/): when people click on "+1", the number increases, but if you refresh the page, the number is the same than before.

The worst : then the button is red (so Google see that the visitor plused) but his "+1" is not recorded.

It worked once (some monthes ago) but now it's over.

Shares (and +1 on shares) are ok, but not "+1" on the website.

Some idea to help me ?

Answer (score 1):

Your page does have some issues that may or may not be the issue:

- On your home page, you are incuding the Google+ JavaScript over and over again with each listed article.  Only include the plusone.js file a single time on any page. At the very least, you'll improve performance from load time and from the DOM scanning that the script does.
- On your article pages, you are also including the plusone.js file multiple times, but also in different manners, sometimes you're loading it asynchronously (desired) and other times its loaded synchronously (not efficient).
- There appears to be a problem fetching the snippet from your page, for example, the thumbnail is broken and the script is returning a `HTTP 500` internal server error. Check your pages with the [Structured data testing tool](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets). This *could* be a Google bug, but you should verify that your own code is correct too.

Answer (score 0):

In my testing the +1's were getting recorded but sometimes the count of 1 was displayed and sometimes the count of 0 was displayed. It looks like a bug on Google's side so you should file a [bug report](https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/entry?template=Bug%20-%20Plugins).

Comment: Thank you for the Google Plus bug report link, done [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=685&thanks=685&ts=1381737204)